# Trying to analyse lottery numbers

Tags: sql, analysis

So import csv file with numbers of winning lottery to [lottery table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C87DQ.png) and i want to know how often each number is draw.

i made it only for 1 number using something like this

```
select count(id), n1
from lotto 
group by n1
having count(id) > 100
order by count(id) desc
```

[Group by number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbGW6.png)

and cant figure it out to make it for all numbers at once(tried weird self join)

```
select lt1.count(id) as c1, 
lt1.n2 as number2,
lt2.count(id) as c2,
lt2.n3 as number3
from lotto lt1, lotto lt2 
where lt1.count(id) <> lt2.count(id)
group by number2, number3
```

without success :(

any idea?

Comment: Do you want a column per number like 1 column for `n1` another for `n2`?

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: im using db2 on cloud, and as i show in "group by number" table i tryng to get it for n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6(for each count(id) to know most often drawn number)(second code showing error. "A reference to column "ID" is ambiguous.. SQLCODE=-203, SQLSTATE=42702, DRIVER=4.27.25")